# Problems with Matlab script to numerically solve projectile motion

Tags: matlab, modeling, projectile

currently I have an assignment to write a Matlab script to numerically solve the problem of a cannonball fired from a variety of angles, both with and without air friction. Of course, I'm trying to think on how to solve the air friction component, but first I need to create the model without air friction, and I cannot figure out for the life of me how it's breaking down. Here's my code:

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;

% Setting initial conditions such as angle, number of sampling intervals,
% initial x- and y-positions, etc.
N_points=10000;
total_time=200;
angle_initial=20;
gravity_initial=9.81;
velocity_initial=700;
y_initial=0;
x_initial=0;

% Set time vector, x-position and y-position vectors, their initial values,
% and sampling interval.

delta_t=total_time/N_points;
y=zeros(N_points,1);
x=zeros(N_points,1);
time=zeros(N_points,1);
y(1)=y_initial;
x(1)=x_initial;

%Begin loop to actually calculate y-position through time.
%

for step=1:N_points-1
    time(step+1)=time(step)+delta_t;
    y(step+1)=y(step)+((-gravity_initial*sind(angle_initial)*time(step+1)+velocity_initial*sind(angle_initial))*delta_t);
end

% Find all values of y-position vector less than zero and eliminate them
% from vector, thus giving us only points before the projectile 'hits' the
% ground.

a_1=find(y<0);
r_1=[a_1];
y(r_1)=[];
b_1=length(y)

%Create x-position vector starting from zero to maximum possible range of
%projectile, separated into equal intervals corresponding to number of
%positive elements in the y-position vector. This way, the x- and y-vectors
%will match when they are plotted together.
x=linspace(0,((velocity_initial^(2))/gravity_initial)*sind(2*angle_initial),b_1);

%plot x- and y-position vectors.
plot(x,y,'r')
```

I can't figure out why the function is 'blowing up' as it were; when this code is run, the range for the projectile is correct, however the height is not. I really cannot see where I'm going wrong here; I have looked through many examples and other things online, and no matter what variation I try, they all exhibit a trajectory height that is much too high. Could anyone provide a clue as to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: In your `y` equation, you should be using `y_initial` instead of `y(step)`. Also the acceleration is purely in the vertical direction so you shouldn't multiply it by `sind()`.

Comment: The velocity term in that same equation should use `time(step+1)` rather than `delta_t`.